# Cron automatically detect jruby path and execute ruby script

Tags: cron, jruby

I've a cron job that is supposed to execute a ruby script but it is failing with:

```
/bin/sh: 1: jruby: not found
```

I know I can set manually jruby location but I want cron to pick automatically as this will be deployed in different machines which have different paths of jruby locations.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: maybe replacing `jruby` command with `bin/jruby` help!

Answer (score 0):

I think [env](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) is your friend.

Assuming JRuby isn't installed in multiple locations on a given box, `/usr/bin/env jruby` is a more portable means of having the system pick the first `jruby` instance it finds on the path.

Just make sure the JRuby *is* actually installed somewhere on the root users' PATH (or whatever user the jruby command runs as).

Comment: It still spits out a similar error                              /usr/bin/env: jruby: No such file or directory

Comment: Right, so where do you have jruby installed?